# In which PHP version PDO::execute() behavior was changed to treat input arrays in a more strict way?

Tags: php, pdo

The query is

```
$statement = $dbh->prepare("select * from tableName");
$statement->execute(array(
                    ':frm' => 0,
                    ':to' => 500
                    ));
```

Question is why it works under PHP ver. 5.3.3 but fails under PHP ver. 5.6.3 and is there anything else other than PHP version which is effecting the result.

I do understand that

> if more keys exist in input_parameters than in the SQL specified in
>   the PDO::prepare(), then the statement will fail and an error is
>   emitted.

Comment: Aren't you missing the WHERE part in the query?

Comment: If I have to guess I would say that 5.6.3 has more security checks then if it fails there.......as you are giving parameter values for non existing parameters.......

Comment: Relying on the fact that something that is obviously wrong 'works' in one version of any programming language is asking for trouble in future versions where the bug that allows it to 'work' is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The answer you can find on this site: http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.execute.php

> The keys from input_parameters must match the ones declared in the SQL. Before PHP 5.2.0 this was silently ignored.